# Can YTD Video Downloader download YouTube playlists having more than 100 videos?

Tags: windows-7, download, youtube

I passed the URL https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8990452B640AD6D5 but it only fetches the first 100 videos.

[image]

(*FL Studio 11-Time Stretch* is the video #100 in the playlist).

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and [YTD Video Downloader](http://www.ytddownloader.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the others manually at sites like http://www.keepvid.com/, but that could be very lengthy depending on how many more videos there are. If there are too many videos, I would recommend using some type of automation software to perform the mouse and keyboard actions for you. For windows 7, I think there's a variety programs that can do this.

To answer your question:
As far as I know, YTD cannot do this.

Comment: FYI I found a program that can download a playlist containing more than 100 videos: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13626/903